# cdonts attachment email

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, cdonts

Is there a way to have ASP classic cdonts email, have an file attached to the form and send it with Via email as an attachment.

If there's a way how would you do it? do you need like tird party dll files.

Ok so I need an example that allows you to attach whatever files you'd like attach on the form then when you hit the submit button the email will be sent out with the attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the zip file from [this website](http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-asp-lzVfnQzk/) which includes sample code doing exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what did not work, what errors did you get? Can you pots your code, then may be we can help you futher.

Comment: Ok so I need an example that allows you to attach whatever files you'd like then when you hit the submit button the email will be sent out with the attachment.